# How do I install mods on a Mac?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I want to install a mod (specifically, [Ravenhearst](https://7daystodie.com/forums/showthread.php?76822-Ravenhearst-Mod)), but [the mod launcher](https://7daystodie.com/forums/showthread.php?48537-The-7D2D-Mod-Launcher-A-Mod-Launcher-for-7-Days-to-Die) only works on Windows. Is it possible to install mods on Mac?

Answer (score 3):

1. Uninstall 7dtd. Open Finder, from taskbar choose Go -> Home. Open Library -> Application Support -> Steam -> steamapps -> common. Delete 7 Days to Die folder. Reinstall 7 Days to Die.
2. Unzip downloaded mod. Open unzipped folder. You should see 4 folders: 7DaysToDie_Data, 7DaysToDieServer_Data, Data, and Mods. I will be referring to this as a “home screen”.
3. Open Steam. In your games Library, right-click 7 Days to Die and choose Properties from the drop-down menu. Choose the LOCAL FILES tab and choose BROWSE LOCAL FILES.
4. Copy & paste (do not drag-and-drop) the Mods folder to this location.
5. Open 7DaysToDie_Data -> Managed.
6. Right-click 7DaysToDie.app and choose Show Package Contents. Here you should see 2 folders: Contents and Data. This will be the other “home screen”.
7. Open Contents -> Resources -> Data -> Managed.
8. Copy & paste (do not drag-and-drop) the .dll files into this location. Mac OSX will ask if you want to keep both or replace. Choose replace.
9. Navigate back to each home screen.
10. Drag-and-drop the 7DaysToDie_Data, 7DaysToDieServer_Data, and Mods folders into this location.
11. Open the Data folders in each location. You will see there are Config, Prefabs, and UMATextures folders in each.
12. For each of these three folders, open up its corresponding folder so you can see the contents. Drag-and-drop the mod’s contents into its respective folder. For duplicate files, mac OSX will ask if you want to Skip, Stop, or Replace. Check the “Apply to All” checkbox, then choose Replace.
13. Start 7 Days to Die and enjoy the mod!

Comment: You have to uninstall the game in order to install a mod in 7D2D on a Mac? Seems harsh.